# If function_1 contains $.each() functions and an on("load") function, how to make function_2 run afterwards?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, each, jquery-callback, jquery-delegate

I've spent the day reading about `deferred`, `done`, `promise` and `callbacks` as they seemed relevant to my problem, as well as the many posts on `'how do i run function_2 after function_1'` etc.

So I understand the concept that when things happen asynchronously, you need to handle them specifically with one of the above approaches.

In my scenario, `function_1` contains `$.each()` loops and an `on.("load"...)` function.

I want to run `function_2` when `function_1` has finished.

If I simply call:

```
function_1();
function_2();
```

They don't run sequentially and I am guessing because either `$.each` or `on.("load"...)` works asynchronously.

If I try to call `function_2` with:

```
function_1.done(function_2());
```

I get:

`TypeError: function_1.done is not a function.`

This leads me to think (and I could be completely off track by this point), that `function_1` does not have that method available.

So my questions, possibly based on incorrect assumptions, are:

- What type of object is returned from `function_1` (if it contains `$.each()` and `on.("load"...)` functions?
- Can I enforce that `function_1` does have the `done()` method available?

**jsFiddle**

As well as the above approach using `done()`, I tried using a `callback` which didn't work, although perhaps my method of replicating something that takes time was not correct:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/xFX8a/2/

```
// function 1
function function_1(callback) {
// replicating something that takes a while
// alert("1");
setTimeout(function() {
$("p").append("This should happen first.");
}, 300);
callback();
}

//function 2
// only do this when function one has finished
function function_2() {
alert("This should happen second.");   
};

// the call
function_1(function_2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback solution would work perfectly, except you're calling the callback in the wrong place:

```
// function 1
function function_1(callback) {
    // replicating something that takes a while
    // alert("1");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("p").append("This should happen first.");
        callback(); // <=== Here, when the thing is done
    }, 300);
    // callback();  // <=== Not here, when you've only started it and it's not done yet
}
```

If you want to use promises instead of an explicit callback, you can do that too. Promises are not part of the JavaScript language; JavaScript functions do not make promises available by themselves, which is why `function_1.done` didn't work. *You* create the promise (with jQuery, in the form of a `Deferred` object) and *return* it from the function, then use it with the other function:

```
// function 1
function function_1() {
    var d = new $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("p").append("This should happen first.");
        d.resolve();    // <=== Resolve the deferred, now that the action is complete
    }, 300);
    return d.promise(); // <=== Return the Promise for the Deferred
}

//function 2
// only do this when function one has finished
function function_2() {
    alert("This should happen second.");   
};

// the call
function_1().done(function_2);
```